# DrawRect is not displaying the image

Tags: xcode

In my Application am trying to display an image in a rectangle and am using DrawRect method.The problem is at the output am seeing nothing.Only blank screen in simulator.Here is the code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      [self drawRect:CGRectMake(78, 43, 222, 138)];
 }

 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btbp.jpg"];

    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 400);

    [myImage drawInRect:imageRect];
    //[self setNeedsDisplay];

    [myImage release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no effect in invoking drawRect. instead you should invoke setNeedsDisplay to enforce redrawing.

Comment: How can i do this can you tell me am new to this platform please

Comment: ok, it's quite easy. when you need redraw your view content, you do call [self setNeedsDisplay] within any method of your class except drawRect. by the way, is your project for iPhone SDK?

Comment: ya my project is for iPhone SDK only.Even i wrote the             [self setNeedsDisplay] within another method.Am not getting a warning that method without matching type and the app is crashing if i ignore and run the app

Comment: in this case there is another technique. setNeedsDisplay is applied only to Mac OS X applications. you can look at Apple's QuartzDemo sample code http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuartzDemo/Listings/Quartz_QuartzImages_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007531-Quartz_QuartzImages_m-DontLinkElementID_28

Comment: ya mine is MAC OS X application only.Still am not getting why??

Comment: can you say exactly what is the type of your app: Mac OS or iPhone?

Comment: sorry actually am using mac os